# Is it implied that a publisher also holds the copyright of a song?

Tags: album, copyright, songwriter

I came across an instance in an album booklet where it lists the publishers of a track. What was interesting about this particular booklet was the way it lists its publishers. Before the first publisher there's © symbol followed by the rest of publishers:

[image]

Does imply that the copyright belongs to, in this case *EMI Blackwood Music Inc.* or *EMI Blackwood Music Inc* and *Dam Rich Music*? Or does this imply that this is the beginning of a list of copyright holders?

Additionally, as the title states, is it implied that a publisher also holds the copyright of a song?

Answer (score 3):

The above means the copyright is held by EMI Blackwood Music and Dam Rich Music.

The owner of copyright differs depending on the contract.  The copyright holder is not always the same as the publisher.